# Java Web Services with GlassFish and Remote Connections

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

Currently I have a Windows 2008 R2 server. On this server I have installed Glassfish 3.1. On my server, I also have a copy of Netbeans installed. I use Netbeans to develop a web service. I can get Netbeans to deploy the web service I have created correctly to Glassfish, but it deploys on localhost. Do I need to modify Glassfish or Netbeans so that the web service is deployed on the public ip address for the server and not local host?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the web service available on all network interfaces?  Just try accessing it on the public IP-number.  Note that the Metro web service stack can auto generate the WSDL for you.

Comment: Why do you need to deploy to a remote server from the IDE? Isn't it possible to work with the local installation? You could then setup your continuous integration server to deploy to remote servers.

Comment: Im new to web services. I didnt know how to deploy them without using the ide.

Comment: @Thorbjorn Yes, I did not realize I would still be able to access it on the public ip. That worked fine.

Comment: When you run the web service within the ide it is being deployed to a local instance of glassfish that is running within the netbeans ide. I do believe that you can set the web service to deploy to the server that it will be running on but you'll have to check the help doc in netbeans to confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish in the standard configuration binds to all network interfaces (i.e. responds on all IP-numbers the machine has).

Hence, if you have deployed it to Glassfish on a machine you should be able to access it with an URL pointing to any of the machines names or IP-numbers.